# Simplifying the derivative of $x^{\frac{2}{3}} \cdot (6-x)^{\frac{1}{3}}$

Tags: calculus

$$x^{\frac{2}{3}} \cdot (6-x)^{\frac{1}{3}}$$

So I get:

$$-x^{\frac{2}{3}} \cdot \frac{1}{3} (6-x) ^{\frac{-2}{3}} + (6-x) ^{\frac{1}{3}} \cdot \frac{2}{3} x ^ {\frac{-1}{3}}$$

How does one go about simplifying this?

I guess I can pull out common terms like this:

$$\frac{1}{3} x ^{-\frac{1}{3}} (6-x)^{\frac{-2}{3}} ( -x + (6-x) \cdot 2)$$

Is that right?

Comment: Your last expression ($\dfrac 23 x ^{1/3}$) should be $\dfrac 23 x^{-1/3}$

Comment: You could try finding a common denominator.

Comment: The differentiation is correct. I wouldn't bother simplifying unless there's something you need to do with the answer. In particular, on an exam trying to simplify (if  it's not called for) just introduces a place to make a mistake.

Comment: The standard method for these type of expressions (arising from use of the product rule) is to factor out the LEAST POWER of each expression, where "least" is taken in the numerical number line sense (i.e. $-3$ is less than $1).$ Since the exponents for factors having the same base differ by $1$ (this is an artifact of the fact that the derivative of an exponentiated expression has an exponent that is one less than the un-differentiated expression), this method of factoring cleans things up nicely (for later use in sign charts for the first derivative test, among other things).

Comment: The error Andrew notes appears to be a typo, since your later simplification attempt is correct. Now, notice that you can simplify $(-x+(6-x)\cdot 2)$.

Comment: Logarithmic differentiation (i.e. taking logs first then differentiating) can make this and similar problems much easier to render into a simplified form

Answer (score 2):

$$f^3 (x)=x^2 (6-x) $$

by differentiation

$$3f^2 (x)f'(x)=2x (6-x)-x^2=3x (4-x) $$

thus

$$f'(x)=\frac {x (4-x)}{f^2 (x)} $$

$$=\frac {x (4-x)}{x^\frac43 (6-x)^\frac23} $$

$$=\frac {4-x}{(6-x)^\frac23}x^{\frac {-1}{3}}$$

Answer (score 1):

> Pulling out this common factor is fine. We can simplify the last expression slightly more and obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{-x^{\frac{2}{3}}}&\color{blue}{ \cdot \frac{1}{3} (6-x) ^{-\frac{2}{3}} + (6-x) ^{\frac{1}{3}} \cdot \frac{2}{3} x ^ {-\frac{1}{3}}}\\
> &=\frac{1}{3}x^{-\frac{1}{3}}(6-x)^{-\frac{2}{3}}(-x+(6-x)2)\\
> &=\frac{1}{3}x^{-\frac{1}{3}}(6-x)^{-\frac{2}{3}}(12-3x)\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=x^{-\frac{1}{3}}(6-x)^{-\frac{2}{3}}(4-x)}
> \end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

We've got to preserve the terms here, and we see that the ordering is mismatched, as in

$$\frac{d}{dx}(x^{\frac{2}{3}}(6-x)^{\frac{2}{3}})=\frac{2}{3}(\frac{6-x}{x})^{\frac{1}{3}}-\frac{1}{3}(\frac{x}{6-x})^{\frac{2}{3}}$$

Then we can factor out $(\frac{6-x}{x})^{\frac{1}{3}}$ to make the second term much nicer with no powers

Your answer and this one are ultimately the same

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^{\frac{2}{3}} \cdot (6-x)^{\frac{1}{3}}\right)=\frac{d}{dx}\left((6x^2-x^3)^{\frac13}\right)=\frac{1}{3}(6x^2-x^3)^{-\frac{2}{3}}(12x-3x^2)=\\
\frac{4x-x^2}{(6x^2-x^3)^{\frac{2}{3}}}=\frac{4x-x^2}{x^{\frac{4}{3}}(6-x)^{\frac23}}=\frac{4-x}{x^{\frac{1}{3}}(6-x)^{\frac23}}.$$